# Import data from excel in gridview at runtime and make changes in gridview save it back to excel at runtime

Tags: excel, c#-4.0

I am displaying values in data grid view fetching data from excel sheet, now I want to add,delete data from gridview at runtime the same changes should reflect in excel sheet how can i do that plz help
I thought of taking checkbox columns bt how to retrieve the checked value at runtime and those value I have to insert in the exact place in excel as of DGV.